# Jquery Repeater in Datapicker or Date Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

**Hello guys**

I am using jquery repeater library. I have jquery datapicker inside my codes, but it doesn't appear in the augmented content after the first option.

What path should I follow. My codes are as follows.

```
My Project : https://codepen.io/metinsarac/pen/WNEMQpy
```

**summary** : I am not using date in jquery repeater.

Thank you very much for your help. I am very grateful to you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In addition to the link to your Code Pen, please provide a snippet of the code in your post. The first thing I see is that your ID is not unique after you hit "Add" button. Also the new field is not initialized with Datepicker, so it does not respond. You will want to ensure that the ID is unique and that the new item is initialized with Datepicker.

Comment: Thank you very much for your information. When I name the input, the name repeats, but as you mentioned, I cannot repeat the id. How healthy will it be to repeat the id? Do I need to create an unlimited datepicker?

Comment: I would suggest using Class names instead of IDs. There are all sorts of issues you can encounter with repeated IDs. Either increment the ID `datepicker-1`, `datepicker-2` etc or switch to classes. You will still need initialize each new field with Datepicker.

Comment: Considering that there are 100 repeaters, should I generate 100 $( "....." ).datepicker() and I don't know how to repeat the id yet.

Comment: I would advise initializing Datepicker by Class, after the item(s) have been created. It will happen for all the items with that class. `$(".datepicker").datepicker();` for example, will happen for 1 or 100 items.

Comment: I was really surprised by this situation, when I was thinking what difference class or id could make, it really worked. I never thought it was this easy. Thank you my friend. I'm also updating the codepen.